# Creating an array of classes not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an array of classes using a vector, but I think I'm getting the syntax wrong from instantiating the array. The error I'm getting is:

`error: request for member 'setX' in objects[0], which is of non-class type 'std::vector'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

class A {
    public:
        void setX(int a) { x = a; }
        int getX() { return x; }
    private:
        int x;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<A> *objects[1];

    objects[0].setX(5);
    objects[1].setX(6);

    cout << "object[0].getX() = " << objects[0].getX() << "\nobject[1].getX() = " << objects[1].getX() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: By the way... By declaring the size with a 1... This will make the size 1... Not 2. It looks like you were thinking in vb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<A> objects; // declare a vector of objects of type A
objects.push_back(A()); // add one object of type A to that vector
objects[0].setX(5); // call method on the first element of the vector
```

Comment: The answer could use a bit more explainatory text, but it's definitely correct so I don't really see what the downvotes are for.

Comment: @Grozz `A` is a class, not a function...So how is it being called in `objects.push_back( A() )`??

Comment: A() is the default constructor for an object of type A.  It's a nameless temporary being passed into vector::push_back().

Answer (score 3):

With an asterisk and a square brackets, you are declaring an array of pointers to vectors instead of a vector. With `std::vector<T>` you do not need square brackets or an asterisk:

```
std::vector<A> objects(2); // 2 is the number of elements; Valid indexes are 0..1, 2 is excluded

objects[0].setX(5); // This will work
objects[1].setX(6);
```

The reason the compiler thought that you were trying to call `setX` on a `vector` is that the square bracket operator, overloaded by the vector, is also a valid operator on an array or a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

An array and `std::vector` are two completely different container types.  An array is actually a fixed-size block of memory, where-as a `std:vector` object is a dynamic sequential container type, meaning it can be dynamically "grown" and "shrunk" at run-time, and the object itself manages the memory allocation of the objects it owns.  Their apparent similarities are that both can access members in O(1) complexity and can use the bracket syntax for accessing members.

What you want is something like the following:

```
int main() 
{

    //make a call to the std::vector<T> cstor to create a vector that contains
    //two objects of type A
    std::vector<A> objects(2);

    //you can now access those objects in the std::vector through bracket-syntax

    objects[0].setX(5);
    objects[1].setX(6);

    cout << "object[0].getX() = " << objects[0].getX() << "\nobject[1].getX() = " << objects[1].getX() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you however do not require your data structure to have a dynamic size, then use an array. Indexing will be faster. Especially if the size is set at compile time

Comment: The potential difference between indexing an array and a vector will be in the nanosecond  range, and most often not important. Using a vector will save you from all kinds of other problems.

Answer (score -1):

here what you did is define an array with 1 element of type *std::vector**, you may want to read more about [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) and [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) first.

The correct way to define it is:

```
std::vector<A> objects(2);
```

or using pointers if that is what you intend to

```
std::vector<A*> objects(2);
objects[0] = new A();
objects[1] = new A();
```

Comment: That won't work ... you can't assign using `operator=` an `A*` to a `std::vector<A*>` object ... you have to insert it using `push_back`.  You also end up with an extra layer of indirection, making this approach very inefficient...

Comment: @Jason of course I can, push_back is to add new element at the end, but I already have 2 elements in the vector, I just what to assign it a value.

Comment: Okay, if you think this works, then please explain why your code won't compile: http://ideone.com/Svx0O

Comment: @Jason sorry, my fault. there is a typo in my code: objects[2] should be objects() -> That is how we call vector's constructor. updated.